How Firefox is working without gekodriver?
I just started using Selenium after 5 years. I remember selenium doesn't work without the gekodriver in path. Today I was following the getting started guide from Selenium doc and there were no mention of downloading or setting path for gekodriver executable either. Right now, I don't have it in path environment variable nor installed at all, yet automation are launching. What changed?

It's 2024. should have ChatGPT first. It's a feature from selenium_manager
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/
